# How to preserve trailing zeros?

Tags: python, pandas, tabulate

I'm outputting a pandas dataframe to a report I'm writing, which is easy as you can now do `df.to_markdown()` to convert the dataframe to a markdown table, and then pandoc can generate the report.

And we can control the specific formatting details quite finely, by passing `floatfmt=".3g"` as a parameter, the operation of which is explained very clearly [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html):

> ... The precise rules are as follows: suppose that the result formatted with presentation type 'e' and precision p-1 would have exponent exp. Then, if m <= exp < p, where m is -4 for floats and -6 for Decimals, the number is formatted with presentation type 'f' and precision p-1-exp. Otherwise, the number is formatted with presentation type 'e' and precision p-1. In both cases insignificant trailing zeros are removed from the significand, and the decimal point is also removed if there are no remaining digits following it, unless the '#' option is used...

Except I do not want trailing zeros to be removed, and I can't see a simple way to prevent them being.

If you want a *reproducible example*, here you go:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'Numbers':[0.100, 0.123, 0.101, 0.099, 0.120, 0.012]})
print(df.to_markdown(showindex=False, floatfmt=".2g"))
```

gives

```
|   Numbers |
|----------:|
|     0.1   |
|     0.12  |
|     0.1   |
|     0.099 |
|     0.12  |
|     0.012 |
```

I could change it to specify decimal figures, like so

```
print(df.to_markdown(showindex=False, floatfmt=".2f"))
```

which gives

```
|   Numbers |
|----------:|
|     0.10  |
|     0.12  |
|     0.10  |
|     0.10  |
|     0.12  |
|     0.01  |
```

--but **that's not what I want**. I want two significant figures. With trailing zeros. Like this:

```
|   Numbers |
|----------:|
|     0.10  |
|     0.12  |
|     0.10  |
|     0.099 |
|     0.12  |
|     0.012 |
```

Comment: You can't, not without converting to strings. `0.100` becomes `0.1` before it even passed to pandas.

Comment: @Scott, I've edited the question to show exactly what I want.

Comment: "In both cases insignificant trailing zeros are removed from the significand, and the decimal point is also removed if there are no remaining digits following it, unless the '#' option is used"  Have you tried using `floatfmt="#.2g"`?

Comment: @Steven Rumblaski -- no i hadn't, and yes it works! If you put it as an answer I'll accept it :) Thankyou :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to keep the significant trailing zeros use `#`.

So change

```
floatfmt=".2g"
```

to

```
floatfmt="#.2g"
```

Comment: And I'd even included that in my question... feeling slightly stupid now :S But thank you very much :)

Comment: That's okay. Sometimes the docs would be clearer with more examples.

Comment: It is setting no. of significant digits and not the no. of decimals.